# Do i need to initialize my ArrayList when i'm reading from sharedpreferences?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I'm adding items to my arraylist in onCreate from sharedPrefences, but do i need to initialize my arraylist before doing this?

```
private ArrayList<Song> songList = null;

//Initialize mSharedPreferences
storageUtil = new StorageUtil(this);

//Load values from mSharedPreferences
songList = storageUtil.getRecentPlayed();
```

Or do this

```
private ArrayList<Song> songList = null;

songList = new ArrayList<>();

//Initialize mSharedPreferences
storageUtil = new StorageUtil(this);

//Load values from mSharedPreferences
songList = storageUtil.getRecentPlayed();
```

First one works fine and in log it shows my items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The `songList` variable value is completely replaced by `songList = storageUtil.getRecentPlayed();`. Initializing a value is not needed if you're throwing it into the garbage collector first thing. In fact, even setting it to `null` initially isn't doing anything. Your code should be:

```
storageUtil = new StorageUtil(this);
private ArrayList<Song> songList = storageUtil.getRecentPlayed();
```

Answer (score 2):

If `storageUtil.getRecentPlayed()` returns an `ArrayList<Song>` (which I believe it does), then you can simply apply it to your variable, since the method already initializes the `ArrayList`.

You don't need to initialize the ArrayList before.

I'm sorry for being short on my answer, I'm typing on my phone

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `getRecentlyPlayed()` is a `getter`. it returns the property of a class without directly exposing the property itself. so `storageUtil` would be replaced by the value from `getRecentlyPlayed()`, therefore initializing it.